# Error: [Err_ HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the Client

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json

I try to send several jsons using table_data, but when I do this I get an error in the res.send

[image]

```js
app.post('/contenido', async (req, res)=> 
{       
    if (req.session.loggedin) {
        
        const area = req.body.area;
        
        const query = 'SELECT * FROM tabla';
        connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
            console.log(area)
            console.log(results)
            res.render('tabla',{
                login: true,
                name: req.session.name,
                rol: req.session.rol,
                area: area,
                tabla_data: results,
                cd: req.session.user,
                contenido: false,
            });
        });

} 
});
```